# Woocommerce: Minimum Quantity for Overall Product Category, not variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So, I already have a plugin ("Advanced Product Quantities") installed that allows me to set minimum quantities for categories and products. However, what I'm trying to do is set a minimum quantity for an overall product/category rather than a minimum for each of its individual variations. To put this into context, I have a baked goods business where I sell bagels. A customer needs to order a minimum of 12 bagels. They can order however many bagels of each kind that they want (for ex: 4 poppy seed, 5 plain, 3 onion, etc.), so long as they order a minimum of 12 bagels total.

When I set a category minimum for the bagel category, it makes each product variation in the shopping cart increase its quantity to 12 to fulfill checkout, rather than recognize that they are all a type of bagel and therefore fulfill the overall bagel minimum of 12 bagels.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get this minimum quantity concept working for my situation?

Comment: Can you tell me the category ID of the `bagel` ?

Comment: The category is simply "bagels" ...Not sure how you find the exact ID for woocommerce category IDs, but it's the only category I have set, and it has a count set for 1.

Comment: Do you have an access of the database ?

Comment: yes, you mean through my server's File Manager?

Comment: No ..Not File manager ... Actual database like phpmyadmin ..

Comment: yes I do @Rohil_PHPBeginner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69172/discussion-between-rohil-phpbeginner-and-user3696987).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out this code:

```
    // Set minimum quantity per product before checking out
    add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'rohil_set_min_total' );
    function rohil_set_min_total() {
        // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
        if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {

            global $woocommerce, $product;
            $i=0;
            //loop through all cart products
            foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) :


                // Set minimum product cart total
                $minimum_cart_product_total = 12;

                // See if any product is from the bagel category or not
                if ( has_term( 'bagels', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) ) :

                    $total_quantity += $product['quantity'];

                endif;

            endforeach;

            if( $total_quantity < $minimum_cart_product_total ) {
                // Display our error message
                wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s products is required from bagel category before checking out.</strong>'
                    . '<br />Current number of items in the cart: %s.',
                    $minimum_cart_product_total,
                    $total_quantity ),
                'error' );
            }

        }

    }
```

**EDITED:**

```
    // Set minimum quantity per product before checking out
    add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'rohil_set_min_total' );
        function rohil_set_min_total() {
            // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
            if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {

                global $woocommerce, $product;
                $i=0;
                //loop through all cart products
                foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) :


                    // Set minimum product cart total
                    $minimum_cart_product_total = 12;

                    // See if any product is from the bagel category or not
                    if ( has_term( 'bagels', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) ) :

                        $total_quantity += $product['quantity'];

                    endif;

                endforeach;

                if ( has_term( 'bagels', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) ) :
                    if( $total_quantity < $minimum_cart_product_total ) {
                        // Display our error message
                        wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s products is required from bagel category before checking out.</strong>'
                            . '<br />Current number of items in the cart: %s.',
                            $minimum_cart_product_total,
                            $total_quantity ),
                        'error' );
                    }
                endif;

            }

        }
```

**New EDITED**

```
    // Set minimum quantity per product before checking out
    add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'rohil_set_min_total' );
        function rohil_set_min_total() {
            // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
            if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {

                global $woocommerce, $product;
                $i=0;
                //$prod_id_array = array();
                //loop through all cart products
                foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) :


                    // Set minimum product cart total
                    $minimum_cart_product_total = 12;

                    // See if any product is from the bagel category or not
                    if ( has_term( 'bagels', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) ) :

                        $total_quantity += $product['quantity'];
                        //array_push($prod_id_array, $product['product_id']);
                    endif;

                endforeach;

                foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) :
                    if ( has_term( 'bagels', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) ) :
                        if( $total_quantity < $minimum_cart_product_total && $i == 0 ) {
                            // Display our error message
                            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s products is required from bagel category before checking out.</strong>'
                                . '<br />Current number of items in the cart: %s.',
                                $minimum_cart_product_total,
                                $total_quantity ),
                            'error' );
                        }
                        $i++;
                    endif;
                endforeach;
            }

        }
```

Comment: hi I just messaged you in the chat

Comment: Try out my edited code ... It should work correctly now. Sorry for the trouble :)

Comment: So, it works unless I add another baked good to my cart of bagels. Then the error message disappears even though there aren't 12 bagels. You'll see what I mean if you add 1 bagel to your cart...the error message appears...then add a different type of food, and you'll see the error message disappears (even though the bagel quantity has remained 1).            However, if you add the bagel second (after you've already added something else to your cart), then the error message appears.

Comment: Okay let me check ..Remove accepted answer so that other can also check up in to that question ..

Comment: @user3696987 Please try new edited code and let me know the output.Also test with each and every way and then let me knw the output.

Comment: Okay! So I've tried it a bunch of different ways and it seems like its finally working in every situation! Thank you so much for your patience and help - this was a big problem for me and you helped fix it!